# Unfortunately app has stopped On click

Tags: android

When I am Clicking On Add Friend button my json Give Me Response Of Successfully and  debugger Comes In  If Condition and Debugger Comes if Block My App hAs Unfortunately stopped .....And When Condition is False  App is Running Properly

here Is my Logcate

```
06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while   executing doInBackground()
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
  06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
  06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:107)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:913)
06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):    at com.example.phonebook.UserByIdProfile$addfrnd.doInBackground(UserByIdProfile.java:133)
06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):    at com.example.phonebook.UserByIdProfile$addfrnd.doInBackground(UserByIdProfile.java:1)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 06-13 15:27:30.700: E/AndroidRuntime(22157):   ... 5 more
 06-13 15:27:31.440: E/WindowManager(22157): Activity com.example.phonebook.UserByIdProfile has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42237718 that was originally added here
 06-13 15:27:31.440: E/WindowManager(22157): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.phonebook.UserByIdProfile has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42237718 that was originally added here
06-13 15:27:31.440: E/WindowManager(22157):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
06-13 15:27:31.440: E/WindowManager(22157):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
06-13 15:27:31.440: E/WindowManager(22157):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
06-13 15:27:31.440: E/WindowManager(22157):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
06-13 15:27:31.440: E/WindowManager(22157):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
06-13 15:27:31.440: E/WindowManager(22157):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
06-13 15:27:31.440: E/WindowManager(22157):     at com.example.phonebook.UserByIdProfile$addfrnd.onPreExecute(UserByIdProfile.java:103)
```

and here is my Code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     UserByIdModel tempuser = (UserByIdModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UserById");
        final UserModel user = (UserModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");

        String SenderId=String.valueOf(user.getUser_Id());
     //UserModel u=new UserModel();
     //String SenderId=u.getUser_Id().toString();

        String ReqesterId=String.valueOf(tempuser.getUser_Id());
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SenderUserID",SenderId));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ReceiverUserID", ReqesterId));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
                if(json!=null)
                {
                    if(json.has("msg"))
                      {
                        String message=json.getString("msg");
                            if(message.equals(TAG_MGS))
                               {

                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        UserByIdProfile.this).create();

                                // Setting Dialog Title
                                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

                                // Setting Dialog Message
                                alertDialog.setMessage("Your Friend Request has Been sent");

                                // Setting Icon to Dialog
                                //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

                                // Setting OK Button
                                alertDialog.setButton("Ok",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                                // Write your code here to e
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                    });

                                // Showing Alert Message
                                alertDialog.show();

                                 //Toast.makeText(UserByIdProfile.this,"Your Friend Request Has Been Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                  
                               }
                            else
                               {
                            flag=1;
                               }

                     }

               }    //  return null; 
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //flag=1;
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if(flag==1)
            Toast.makeText(UserByIdProfile.this,"Your friend request has already sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}

 }
```

My Alert box Is Not Working

Comment: You can't modify the UI content inside doInBackground(). So your "alertDialog" can't be created and shown there.

Comment: What should I Do  in if block   for Success....?

Comment: Move your Alert Dialog code to on Post Execute because it runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Raghunandan said what you did. In short: doInBackground should process data and return some kind of result (numeric, enum, object, what ever) and based on that return your onPostExecute method should provide feedback to the user. Update UI with fetched data and/or show an error dialog to inform him that something failed.

Comment: Sorry I m New Thats y i did this Mistake

Comment: please show your aleart dialog in onPostExecute(). you will not face this error any more in future by appling this changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All user interaction part should be done on UI thread only, So remove your `Alert Dialog` code form `doInBackground` and call it in on UI thread. do like this

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
  .
  .
  .
   try {
            if(json!=null)
            {
                if(json.has("msg"))
                  {
                   return json.getString("msg"); 
                    }
                .
                .
                .
     }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //flag=1;
    return null;

   }

   protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    if(msg != null && msg.equals(TAG_MGS)){
           AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    UserByIdProfile.this).create();

                            // Setting Dialog Title
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

                            // Setting Dialog Message
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Your Friend Request has Been sent");

                            // Setting Icon to Dialog
                            //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);

                            // Setting OK Button
                            alertDialog.setButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            // Write your code here to e
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                });

                            // Showing Alert Message
                            alertDialog.show(); 
              }
    .
    .  
   ...
}
```

Comment: Shud i put Else Condition on Post execute  methode

Comment: no you must have to call the Alert's `show` method from UI thread only.

Comment: thanks For this Code Its Working Well .....I want to Learn Plz Can U tell me About Tutorial

Comment: [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html) is best and simple side to learn `Android`. Enjoy....

Answer (score 2):

You are using alertdialog in `doInbackground`. `doInbackground` is invoked on the ui thread. So you should not update ui on the background thread. Use `onPostExecute` and show alertdialog there based on the result returned in `doInbackground`. `onPostExecute` is invoked on the ui thread.

Comment: What to Do For Success

Comment: return success or failure or a boolean then in `onPostExecute` based on result show the alertdialog